# Fastest service wrapper for Java apps

Tags: java, linux, wrapper

I'm looking for most performing Java service wrapper, which could make Java application running as a service on Linux.

Can anyone recommend such utility.

Thanks.

Comment: Try googling for "java init.d script"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Take a look at the jsvc tool from the commons-daemon project.

http://commons.apache.org/daemon/jsvc.html

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend JSVC also,but it seems to require that your apps main class have a "init" method (such as the type that Tomcat has).

```
Java VM created successfully
Class org/apache/commons/daemon/support/DaemonLoader found
Native methods registered
java_init done
Daemon loading...
java.lang.NoSuchMethodException: com.server.Site.init([Ljava.lang.String;)
        at java.lang.Class.getMethod(Class.java:1605)
        at org.apache.commons.daemon.support.DaemonLoader.load(DaemonLoader.java:158)
Cannot load daemon
java_load failed
Service exit with a return value of 3
```